# Illegal State Exception While Navigating through web app? Where does this come from?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, tomcat8

Okay so I am getting an intermittent exception that I can't seem to figure out, I can't seem to reproduce it consistently enough to figure out the issue either. all I have is an exception and a stack trace that maybe you guys can help me out with. I can tell you that I experienced the problem while navigating through my web application from one page to another and back, and so on so fourth just to see that all of my forwards were working properly and that all of my jstl tags were loading properly with the correct information. The stack trace is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started

at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:990)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap(Mapper.java:808)
at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:667)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:862)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Thoughts

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace? No "caused by" or anything else?

Comment: @DavidLevesque That's it there was no caused by message or a pinpoint location where I would be able to search for the cause of the exception... or even a general location I would have taken that

Comment: did you the solution to this problem?